Azure ad b2c custom policy "Your password has expired."
we are using b2c custom policy to login locally. for the newly created user first time login it does authenticate but then get a message "Your password has expired."
And then there is no option to reset password, ideally it should redirect by itself to change password flow
enter image description here
   <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

so execution stops in SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email with password expired message.. it does not move on to next step to "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId"
followed custom policy sample. but think i am missing something. cannot figure it out what's wrong..

To resolve this issue, you can modify your custom policy to include the password reset flow
